# Registering custom taxonomy with unique name, a good practise?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

Is it a good practise to register custom taxonomy with a unique name (the [`$taxonomy` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Parameters)), and then use the `rewrite` argument to set a custom `slug`?

For example, I could create a taxonomy called `list` in two different ways. Like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_lists' );
function custom_taxonomy_lists() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'lists',

        // [...]
    );

}
```

OR, like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_lists' );
function custom_taxonomy_lists() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'john28_lists',

        // [...]

        array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'lists' ),

            // [...]
        )
    );

}
```

What I am asking is, is the latter (the 2nd code block) considered a good practise?

(This is the recommended way for registering custom post types, so I thought maybe it applies to custom taxonomies as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any downside to a more unique taxonomy name, or having the taxonomy name and slug be different. The downside to a dictionary word taxonomy name is a potential conflict if some other code registers a taxonomy with the same name.